# Different use of tenses in Iberian vs South American (and/or Andean) Spanish

Tags: diferencias-regionales, tiempos-verbales, dialectos

Are the tenses in Iberian vs Central/South American Spanish used differently? I know there are a lot of Spanish variants spoken in the Andes, for example. Do all of them use the present perfect (*yo he hablado*) and the past perfect (*yo habia hablado*) in the same way?

I'm very curious about how tense in different varieties of Spanish may differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

I am focusing in the present perfect and its usage in comparison with the simple present.

From [El perfecto simple y el perfecto compuesto en Hispanoamérica: la inclusión o exclusión del ahora de la enunciación → 2. Análisis cuantitativo del perfecto simple y del perfecto compuesto](http://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0071-17132009000100006)

> No hay uniformidad cuantitativa en el empleo de ambas formas en todo el ámbito del español americano, si bien se puede afirmar que **en todos los países hispanoamericanos que forman parte de la muestra, salvo en Bolivia** (que es el único país en el que no existe predominio del perfecto simple sobre el compuesto), **la superioridad del perfecto simple sobre el compuesto**, globalmente, **es mayor que en el español peninsular o canario** (...)
>
> (...) podemos seguir manteniendo que **una de las características del español de América**, puesta de manifiesto reiteradamente desde Kany (1976: 200), **es la preferencia por el perfecto simple**, que tiene, en consecuencia, un campo de acción más amplio que lo que le corresponde en el uso peninsular, aunque esto no equivale a decir que la forma compuesta está en decadencia en el español americano sino que simplemente, tal como señala Moreno de Alba, "su función denotativa es diferente y su campo de acción más reducido" (1978: 187), es decir, no se trata de la confusión del actual uso peninsular, sino de un desarrollo histórico diverso de la misma herencia.

That is, in Spain it is common to say:

> Hoy *he comido* morcilla.

While in Hispanic America they will normally say:

> Hoy *comí* morcilla.

Comment: This is correct however when I want to enumerate all that I've eaten today I'd say _hoy he comido morcilla, chorizo y arepa_ beign _hoy comí morcilla_ more common when speaking about a single thing. I just realized we do that while reading this answer.